# Perform an assignment and an operation using a ternary operator + && in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, syntax, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

In the name of ternary bliss (and for a disdain of the verbose)... I am hoping, and am somewhat surprised that....

```
BOOL isItOpen = YES;
isItOpen = (isItOpen ? YES : NO); // yes, dumbie, it's open.
```

works fine… but that…

```
isItOpen = (isItOpen ? [it close] && NO : [it open] && YES);
```

results in `Invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'int')`

I can't seem to track down a simple yes or no as to whether one can conditionally chain operations with `&&` (or `||`), like one does in say, BASH or PHP.  I tried various combinations of `&` and `&&` arrangements, to no avail.. as I am a `C` idiot... but if this "way of doing it" is NOT possible, linguistically…  is there another - that is as concise? (ie, no `if`s involed?)

Comment: The methods close and open must return a BOOL value to make this work

Comment: @phix23: Or something implicitly convertible to bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference you are experiencing is due to Objective-C having:

(a) true procedures (void functions/methods) which return no value; and
(b) a stronger type system than PHP

In your example the primary problem is (a) - you are calling methods which return *nothing*, and *nothing* is not a boolean value.

In PHP functions always return *something*, a function defined as returning void is actually defined as returning a "useless" value. However PHP will convert just about anything to anything (and does so inconsistently, for added "fun"), so a "useless" value has a boolean value - though what that is probably depends on the phase of the moon ;-) This feature does mean that you can reliably chain a "void" function *after* one which returns a value - `<expr convertible to boolean> && <"void" function>` will work in PHP (but the resulting boolean value is arbitrary). The same thing will not work in Objective-C (do **not** try to fix it with the comma operator, there are hidden traps with that operator).

So provided you stick with functions/methods which return either a boolean, or a type implicitly or explicitly convertible to boolean (e.g. for pointer types `nil` is false, other values true; for integral types 0 is false, everything else true) you can "conditionally chain" operations. Whether you *should* do this is a different question...

P.S. If you want to be confusing, this is short:

```
(isItOpen = !isItOpen) ? [it open] : [it close];
```

which will make most folks do a double-take ;-)

Comment: All good answers, but appreciate the analysis… and short solution, whether it's use is advised, or not  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The C (and by extension, C++ and Objective-C<sup>1</sup>) operators form [*expressions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_%28programming%29); they're designed to evaluate to a value, rather than control program flow.

So whilst `?:`, `&&` and `||` all offer [*short-circuit evaluation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of their arguments, you can't use them to conditionally call arbitrary functions;<sup>2</sup> you should use traditional control-flow constructs (i.e. `if`) for that.

You **could** use the little-known [*comma operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) to achieve this, but I strongly recommend that you **don't**, because it's highly unidiomatic, and difficult to read.  e.g.:

```
isItOpen = condition ? (func1(), NO) : (func2(), YES);
```

---

1. Actually, I don't know Objective-C.  For all know, it might be possible!
2. And by "arbitrary", I mean functions that return `void`, or a type that's not implicitly convertible to `bool` in the case of `&&` and `||`, or a non-matching type in the case of `?:`.

Comment: Not designed for use in the ternary operator, or not anywhere?  For example, does `isItOpen = YES && [it open];` not work, either?  Seems like  kind such a fundamental ability (to chain simple operations based on value or status of the previous value or operation), no?

Comment: @alexgray: Yes, it's true for all the "short-circuit" operators (`?:`, `&&`, `||`).

Answer (score 3):

Your code would work fine as long as the `close` and `open` methods you are executing on `it` return boolean values. Otherwise, no cigar.

Comment: Or something implicitly convertible to bool.

Comment: Unfortunately, the function is not one that I defined - and it returns `void`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the ternary operator, you can do like this:

```
isItOpen ? ([it close], isItOpen = NO) : ([it open], isItOpen = YES);
```

Or:

```
isItOpen ? [it close] : [it open];
isItOpen = !isItOpen;
```

But this is not a good programming style and you should avoid it.

The following code is much more readable (at least by a C/C++/Objective-C programmer):

```
if (isItOpen)
    [it close];
else
    [it open];
isItOpen = !isItOpen;
```

In order of preference, I recommend you use the third version of the code, then the second, then the first.

Comment: I see @OliCharlesworth also suggested using the comma operator. You can use his suggestion like this `isItOpen = isItOpen ? ([it close], NO) : ([it open], YES);` But this is equivalent to the first version in my answer and is equally not recommended.

Comment: These are GREAT solutions (to my question).  As to your recommendations.. while I love objective C (and objective-C programmers), I cringe at how "vertical" it is. (Wasn't it Apple that had us buy all these widescreen displays?)  If you can say something on **1 line, vs. 5**… I say do it… However, your stylistic warnings are well-recieved, and duly noted.